# Linq error when placing method in the where clause:

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to LINQ and I am getting the following error when placing a method within the following Where clause:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String getPrefixBySize(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
adminGalleryDesignerVM.Thumbnails = (from tn in db.Media
from fd in db.FileDescendants
where tn.GalleryId == galleryId && fd.FileId == tn.FileId
&& fd.Prefix == FM.getPrefixBySize(fd.FileId, 250, 250, 1)
   select new FileVM
    {
    id = tn.MediaId,
    FileName = tn.File.FileName,
    URL = FM.getMediaURL(tn.FileId, fd.Prefix),
    Height = fd.FileHeight,
    Width = fd.FileWidth
    }).ToList();
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the signature of getPrefixBySize. It's telling you what it thinks it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinqToEntities will try to convert ALL of the criteria in the query to SQL.  Since it can't directly convert `getPrefixBySize` to SQL, the entire query fails.

You have a few options:

1. Get more data than you need to and filter more using Linq-to-Objects:

   ```
   adminGalleryDesignerVM.Thumbnails = (
       from tn in db.Media
       from fd in db.FileDescendants
       where tn.GalleryId == galleryId && fd.FileId == tn.FileId
          select new 
           {
           id = tn.MediaId,
           FileName = tn.File.FileName,
           tn.FileId, 
           fd.Prefix,
           Height = fd.FileHeight,
           Width = fd.FileWidth
           })
       .AsEnumerable()  // hydrate the query
       .Where(x => x.Prefix == FM.getPrefixBySize(x.FileId, 250, 250, 1)
       .Select(x => new FileVM
           {
           id = x.id,
           FileName = x.FileName,
           URL = FM.getMediaURL(x.FileId, x.Prefix),
           Height = x.Height,
           Width = x.Width
           })
       .ToList();
   ```
2. Replace the call to `getPrefixBySize` with inline functions that can be converted to SQL (if possible) such as basic value comparisons, etc.

Comment: THANKS! I went with the first solution. I just had to cast the method to string, like so: .Where(x => x.Prefix == (string)FM.getPrefixBySize(x.FileId, 250, 250, 1)